# Fast integer matrix null space in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, linear-algebra

I have a Python program that accepts matrices with coefficients that can only be -1, 0 and 1. I need to compute the null space for those matrices. Those matrices can be huge (millions of entries) and performance is critical.

[Scipy's `null_space`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.null_space.html#scipy.linalg.null_space) has acceptable performance, but the problem is that it returns the null space as a orthonormal matrix. I would like the resulting matrix to have integer coefficients.

[Sympy's `nullspace`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/matrices.html#nullspace) returns the matrix I want, however because it's pure Python (and probably also because it uses Gaussian Elimination instead of faster algorithms) has very bad performance.

Is there anything else out there I can try? It would be nice if solutions could be easily parallelized.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a QR decomposition. Scipy is using SVD for nullspace. QR is in principle faster.

Edit: A short search on mathoverflow reveals this https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61861/fast-algorithms-for-computing-nullspace-of-a-positive-semidefinite-matrix-over-z

Comment: Thanks. I know there are many algorithms available. What I'm wondering if there's already a fast *implementation* available out there for Python